# When I upload vertical photo it shows sideway in my php website

Tags: php, uploadify, jcrop

When I upload vertical photo, after uploading it display sideway.

I am using uploadify, and doing simple croping of the image using jQuery Jcrop.

Can anybody give me solution?

Comment: If you want us to help, you should at least post the code you have written that treats the uploaded file.

Comment: can you give some clue before asking for solution ?

Comment: 3 lines out of your 5-line question are just social decorations. Please substitute them with your actual code, and help will flock, guaranteed

Comment: Are you using PHP GD Library?

Comment: I'm just going to guess that that photo is not actually "vertical", but is just flagged as having a certain orientation by your camera/photo editing software/whatever else you use. So it appears in portrait orientation in whatever you use to look at the image, but other software is not honoring that orientation flag and/or it's not even exported with the image file. Hard to say without any information though.

Answer (score 0):

check your css class for displaying image and height and width of the image that you are displaying.